# jython max() 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, jython

I looking for help. 
I managed to add row_id to my file using the following code and it`s working fine.

```
infile = open(inputfile, 'r')
outfile = open(outputfile, 'w')

for i, line in enumerate(infile): 
#write header
    row_sec = ("00000" + str(i))[-5:]
    row_nr = max(row_sec)
    outfile.write(row_sec + "Company" + column[0] + column[1] + row_nr + "\n")
outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

results:

- 00000 - header
- 00001 - data
- 00002 - data
- .... - data
- 00037 - data last line

The problem is that I need to put nr of records in header line (in this case it would be 00037)

when I use

```
records = max(i)
```

or

```
records = max(row_id)
```

I get error 
**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable**

I read about this error and understand it but still can`t figure out how to get rid of it. Is there a clever and simple way to fix my code?

Comment: Can you show the exact code please? And format the question accordingly?

Comment: ``i`` is an integer, whereas ``max`` requires an iterable. What do you expect ``max(i)`` to provide?

Comment: Try reading up on [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and come back when you've done that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I know I`m being silly and this won`t work, also with row_sec since I`ve turned it into string. I want to somehow place the last (so max) row_sec as nr. of rows in my header.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth, thank you

Comment: @Beata Is your file large? Can you keep it in memory at once?

Comment: If you can hold your file in memory, you have the option of reading the `readlines()` into a variable called `lines` (for this example), and write everything your script currently does inside it, and at the end you open your output file in write mode and write the content of the `lines` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delay writing and grab the variables from the loop:

```
buffer = []
for i, line in enumerate(infile): 
    # create line content
    buffer.append('%5d' % i + " Company " + line + "\n")
# i is still set to the last value
# write header
outfile.write('%5d' % i + " Elements\n")
for line in buffer:
    outfield.write(line)
```

This will write something like

```
00037 Elements
00000 Company ACME
00001 Company EMCA
...
00037 Company MECA
```

Note that `enumerate` takes an optional parameter `start` if you need to set the first index.

---

If your file is larger than available memory, you can read it twice instead of buffering:

```
# read once to get number of entries
with open(inputfile, 'r') as infile:
    companies = sum(1 for line in infile)

infile = open(inputfile, 'r')
outfile = open(outputfile, 'w')

# write header
outfile.write('%5d' % companies + " Elements\n")
for i, line in enumerate(infile):
    row_sec = ("00000" + str(i))[-5:]
```

Comment: I got the following error due to the fact that apparently I`m using some old version - SyntaxError: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6

I modified your code a bit so it works for me 
infile = open(inputfile, 'r')
for line in infile:
    rec_nr = sum(1 for line in infile)
infile.close()

rest the same.... And it worked! You have no idea how grateful I am. Thank you very much for all the amazing help.

Comment: @Beata Please upgrade your python version! 2.6 is ancient already, but yours is even older.